# "Easy" vs. "simple"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

Are those two words equivalent or is there a difference? When would I say something is *easy* rather than *simple*, or vice versa?

Comment: Did you look at the [common-available resources](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573)? What exactly is not clear, to you?

Comment: It's simple to become as rich as Donald Trump -- inherit $40 million and invest it at market rate.  Not particularly easy for the average person to pull that off, though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I did but for instance I need to describe *staging* (= a technique of creating [staging sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_site)) as either easy or simple and I'm not sure which one to choose, or what are the subtle differences between them.

Comment: Could you edit your question and explain "why" you are confused as to which word to use. Could you also provide the sentence where this word would fit in. I'd strongly advise you to follow this route if you hope to receive some answers. Show us that you have done a little research otherwise someone will just post the definitions of *easy* and *simple*. Good luck!

Comment: Jumping off the high diving board is very simple (just step off), but not easy (because of psychological issues) for many people.

Comment: **No two words are equivalent.** That's why they are *two* words.

Comment: Bench pressing 10 pounds is simple and easy.  bench pressing 400 pound is just as simple but not as easy!

Comment: @Borek, let me put it to you like this: Your question is very simple, but coming up with a good answer to your question is not very easy... unless you're as smart as me. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I would say the difference lies in the context. If something can be achieved (as a task) without difficulty I would say it was easy. If something can be understood without difficulty I would say it was simple.

> My maths test was easy because the questions were so simple.
>
> The children were given the simple task of reciting the alphabet. Only
>   a few found this task easy; many had difficulties.
>
> Losing weight in theory is simple. Losing weight in practice is not so easy.

Answer (score 3):

*Simple* may refer to a lack of complexity *in an object itself*: it describes the actual object. 'Easy' refers to the *use* of something that might be complex in itself, but whose use has been made straightforward because of eg. good instructions. Example: a door lock with few parts may be called 'simple', but not 'easy' (unless you're talking about how to use it), whereas an instruction manual for an object that makes a complex process do-able because of a good explanation might make that object 'easy' to use (because of the instructions). A door lock might be simple, but it probably won't be easy. Bit vague without knowing the context, but that's arguably one difference between the two words.